# Django inject data after base.html

Tags: python, django

I have a base.html file which is a side bar menu. like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Welcome!</h3>
            </div>
    
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#list">List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

I also have a text file that I want to show the content. So I configured my view like this:

```
def list(request):
    f = open('textFile.txt', 'r')
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    context = {'file_content': file_content}
    print(file_content)
    return render(request, "list.html", context)
```

The destination HTML file which is going to show the data is like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{{ file_content }}
```

The problem is, the text file data is now showing up. and if I remove `{% extends 'base.html' %}` them the text file data shows up, but I lose the side bar. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define some blocks to override using [Django's template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance):

```html
<!--base.html-->
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Welcome!</h3>
            </div>
    
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#list">List</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </main> 
    </div>
</body>


<!--list.html-->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}{{ file_content }}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{% block %}` in your `base.html`. Then when you extend your template, you can specify that `file_content` goes in the block. E.g.:

base.html

```
<div>Sidebar</div>
{% block after_sidebar %}{% endblock %}
```

destination file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block after_sidebar %}
    {{ file_content }}
{% endblock %}
```

See more in [Django Docs - Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#id1)

Answer (score 0):

please read carefully about "`extend`"
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/#templates

in your base.html you should have any blok's tags ( `{% block 'myname' %}{% endblock 'myname' %}`), which you should to extend.

```
<-- base.html -->
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <--  ... any staff here --> 
        </nav>
        {% block 'myname' %}{% endblock 'myname' %}
    </div>
</body>
```

after that:

```
<-- your template -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block 'myname' %}{{ file_content }}{% endblock 'myname' %}
```